# Qt Widgets; how to create a design like QT Creator projects picker

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer, qwidget

I thought it would be rather easy, but now I'm one week in and still very far away. I'm trying to create a welcome screen with a "recently opened" list. The goal was to have it designed somewhat like the projects list in QT Creator:

[image: example]

I thought that I could use some form of list widget, but I haven't found any that fit. So now I'm down to trying to create it by my own. Here is the result so far:

[image: current status]

I've used the following code for that:

```
QGridLayout *childLayout1= new QGridLayout();
QLabel *label1_1 = new QLabel("first label");
QLabel *label1_2 = new QLabel("Child first label");
childLayout1->addWidget(label1_1);
childLayout1->addWidget(label1_2);

QGridLayout *childLayout2= new QGridLayout();
QLabel *label2_1 = new QLabel("second label");
QLabel *label2_2 = new QLabel("Child second label");
childLayout2->addWidget(label2_1);
childLayout2->addWidget(label2_2);


QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout();
mainLayout->addItem(childLayout1, 0, 0);
mainLayout->addItem(childLayout2, 1, 0);

ui->mainFrame->setLayout(mainLayout);
```

And now I'm lost. It looks nowhere near the list picker of QT Creator. In fact, it's not even usable. Does somebody has any pointers for me on how to approach this design question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some rest did wonders and I've got something that looks good enough for now. I hope that this answer can help anybody in the future.

[image]

It uses an a QFrame placed inside a QGridLayout. Using `setRowStretch` on the `QGridLayout` fixes the problem with alignments mentioned in the question. The values used can be tweaked, 25 is a bit to much. But I'm not entirely sure how this works, so I'm leaving it for now as is.

It makes also use of an `eventFilter` to capture a left mouse click on the frame.

Below my mainwindow.h file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class QFrame;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QImage *img = new QImage(":/all/Folder-1.svg");
    QPixmap p = QPixmap::fromImage(*img);

    QFrame *CreateNewRow(int number, QString title, QString subtitle, QString mouseReleaseValue, int generalFontSize=18);

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And my mainwindow.cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QMessageBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QFrame *row1 = CreateNewRow(1, "First row", "First subtitle row", "row_1");
    QFrame *row2 = CreateNewRow(2, "Second row", "Second subtitle row", "row_2");

    QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout();
    // All rows no stretch
    // Not sure about the magic numbers, but it works..
    mainLayout->setRowStretch(25, 25);
    mainLayout->addWidget(row1, 0, 0);
    mainLayout->addWidget(row2, 1, 0);

    ui->mainFrame->setLayout(mainLayout);
}

QFrame* MainWindow::CreateNewRow(int number, QString title, QString subtitle, QString mouseReleaseValue, int generalFontSize)
{
    QString styleFrame = QString("*:hover {background: #F6F6F6;}");
    QString styleNumber = QString("font-size: %1px; color: #8B8D8F;").arg(qRound(generalFontSize * 0.7));
    QString styleTitle = QString("font-size: %1px; color: #5CAA15;").arg(generalFontSize);
    QString styleSubtitle = QString("font-size: %1px; color: #8B8D8F;").arg(qRound(generalFontSize * 0.7));

    QFrame *frame = new QFrame();
    frame->setStyleSheet(styleFrame);
    frame->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
    frame->installEventFilter(this);
    frame->setProperty("mouseReleaseValue", mouseReleaseValue);

    QLabel *imgDisplayLabel = new QLabel("");
    imgDisplayLabel->setPixmap(p.scaled(generalFontSize, generalFontSize, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    imgDisplayLabel->adjustSize();
    imgDisplayLabel->setContentsMargins(5, 0, 10, 0);

    QGridLayout *layout= new QGridLayout(frame);
    // All rows no stretch
    // Not sure about the magic numbers, but it works..
    layout->setColumnStretch(25, 25);

    QLabel *labelNumber = new QLabel(QString::number(number));
    QLabel *labelTitle = new QLabel(title);
    QLabel *labelSubtitle = new QLabel(subtitle);

    labelNumber->setStyleSheet(styleNumber);
    labelTitle->setStyleSheet(styleTitle);
    labelSubtitle->setStyleSheet(styleSubtitle);

    layout->addWidget(labelNumber, 0, 0);
    layout->addWidget(imgDisplayLabel, 0, 1, Qt::AlignVCenter);
    layout->addWidget(labelTitle, 0, 2);
    layout->addWidget(labelSubtitle, 1, 2);

    return frame;
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) {
        QMouseEvent* mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*> (event);
        if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            QString prop = obj->property("mouseReleaseValue").toString();
            QMessageBox msgBox;
            msgBox.setText(QString("You have clicked an object with mouseReleaseValue: %1.").arg(prop));
            msgBox.exec();
            return true;
        }
    }
    // standard event processing
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```